# Normal of a 3-dimensional wave

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, polynomial-math, unityscript, normals

Problem:
    I have a function that calculates the *Y* value (the height) of a wave given the *X* and *Z* coordinates. I also require the normal at this point i.e. the normal of the tangent/gradient at this point.

Background stuff:

- I am trying to simulate the waves of the ocean so that I can have a floating boat that is affected by the waves so that it will rock back-and-forth and side-to-side.
- This is for a game that I am making in unity for a school project.
- I am scripting in C# but Unity also accepts JavaScript
- The water is a plane with multiple vertices so that each vertice's height is calculated by my script (this part is already done).

What I have so far

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weather : MonoBehaviour
{   
        //The height of the waves
        public float amplitude = 0.01f;
        //The number of waves
        public float frequency = 50f;
        //The speed the direction of the waves rotate
        public float directionChange;

        // Update is called once per frame, every frame it is rotated a small amount.
        //using transform.rotate allows for easy rotation and reference to its direction with transform.forward is automaticlly normalised.
        void FixedUpdate ()
        {
                //Rotates around the y axis
                transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.up, directionChange * Time.deltaTime);
        }   

        //Gets the height (y value) of the wave at an (x,z) position. At each frame the amplitude, time, frequency and direction are considered constant so that but these all change with between each frame.
        public float heightAt (float x, float z)
        {
                return amplitude * Mathf.Sin (Time.realtimeSinceStartup + x * frequency * transform.forward.x + z * frequency * transform.forward.z);
        }

        //This needs to use the same function as the heightAt(x, z) method so that the normal at a point can be calculated e.g. the normal at a point on top of the wave would be straight up
        public Vector3 normalAt (float x, float z)
        {
                return Vector3.up;
        }
}
```

My research turned up the chain rule and I have been trying [unsuccessfully] to use this.
The thing I am having difficulty with is getting the normalised vector of the gradient (so that I can then get the normalised vector of the normal)

I need to find the normal so that I can calculate the buoyancy force on a boat through the use of nodes, these nodes can calculate the force to apply to their parent object (the boat) by checking if they are in the water.
If the node is above the wave then it will apply a gravity force to the boat, if below the wave it will use the normal to apply a force so that it will be pushed around by the waves.

Hopefully I have been clear enough that you can understand.
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Do you know calculus?  the x gradient of f(x) = d/dx f(x), the y gradient of f(x) = d/dy f(x), where f is the equation for your wave.  These are partial derivatives.  After you have those you can normalize it by dividing both components by the length (sqrt(x^2 + y^2)).  That's the normalized gradient.

Comment: Also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%28a+*+sin%28t+%2B+x+*+f+*+u+%2B+z+*+f+*+v%29%29) knows calculus ;-)

Comment: Oops, in my first comment it was supposed to say x gradient of f(x,y) is d/dx f(x,y), y gradient is d/dy f(x,y).  The wave is a function of both variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... Should be like this:

```
public Vector3 normalAt (float x, float z)
{
    float argument = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + x * frequency * transform.forward.x + z * frequency * transform.forward.z;
    float nx = amplitude * frequency * transform.forward.x * Mathf.Cos(argument);
    float ny = -1.0f;
    float nz = amplitude * frequency * transform.forward.z * Mathf.Cos(argument);
    return new Vector3(nx, ny, nz).normalized; // Not sure about sign. Maybe you need to multiply the result by -1.
}
```

Comment: Yep that's it. It does need to be multiplied by -1.